# git pull creates an unnecessary merge commit

Tags: git, gerrit

My team uses gerrit to store source code, and we're all developing on `main` branch (team's WoW). Here is the situation I'm deal with:

1. I make some changes in `main`, push it and wait for review. If I run `git status` at this moment, the output looks like below.

```
dustin@linux:~/workspace/proj$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

2. My leader reviews +2 so that my change can be merged to `main` (I do acknowledge it).
3. My teammate makes some changes, these are merged after mine (I do acknowledge it).
4. I need to push another change, I run `git pull`.
5. The terminal opens vim editor, and the commit message looks like this

```
commit 111111111111111111111111111111111111 (HEAD -> main)
Merge: 22222222 33333333
Author: dustin
Date:   Tue May 23 00:00:00 2023

    Merge branch 'main' of ssh://gerrit.com/proj into main
```

while `2222` is my change, `3333` is my teammate's change.

What I expected to result after step 5 is to only update latest change of `main` into my local, no merge commit is needed.

Normally, after the git creates a merge commit, I run `git reset --hard HEAD^` in order to move `HEAD` to `3333`, then run `git pull` and no "merge commit" happens. These steps are quite complex and I think it could be easier. What should I do?

Comment: `git pull --rebase` on step 4.

Comment: @1615903 won't it change history? I'm affraid that If I do `git pull --rebase`, my change will be on my teammate's change, while his change should be on mine.

Comment: @dustin2022 if "your" and "their" changes are two commits that are not reachable from each other (but share the same parent), then there are only two options: merge (with a merge commit) or rebase your commit onto "their" work. There is no "my change on their change" (or vice-versa) without rewriting history – because the history has already both changes side by side.

Comment: There are a lot of misunderstandings about rebasing out there. `git pull --rebase` will rewrite your local copy of the history, not the published one. A force push on a published branch is what you want to avoid. If your own commit was already merged, the rebase will notice that and skip it, which will have the same final effect as your hard reset.

Comment: My general advice: `git fetch` is your friend. I personally never use `git pull`. When I do a `git fetch`, I get all the remote information locally and I can inspect the commit tree and then make my own decision as to whether I want to rebase my local commits, or perform a merge, or whatever. I find `git pull` terrible, because it's saying "yeah, go ahead and merge, no matter what you find on the server". I never want to perform that merge without first analyzing why it might be needed!

Comment: Sorry, that's not quite true: `git pull` is useful if your sandbox is clean and has no commits that are not already on the remote. (But even so, my fingers won't type that command. Instead, I'll type `git fetch` followed by my favourite variants of `git log --all --graph --oneline` and then `git merge` or `git rebase` now that I know exactly what that's going to do.)

Answer (score 3):

You are probably confused because `main` on your local machine is not the same as `main` on the remote, they just happen to be called the same. `pull` is just `fetch` then `merge`, so what you are doing is:

- fetching the remote's `main` (into your local remote branch `remote/origin/main`),
- merging that into your currently checked out branch, which is your local `main`.

If this merge requires a merge commit, it gets created. This is by design.

---

I would suggest to modify your workflow: don't commit directly to a shared branch (`main`). You can probably protect that branch in gerrit.

When you want to update your local `main` to reflect that of the remote, here is the command:

```
git fetch origin main:main
```

When you start work on new stuff:

- fetch the latest commit of main: `git fetch origin main:main` (that way your local `main` matches the remote's `main`, which avoids confusion)
- create a branch specific to that new stuff: `git checkout main && git checkout -b new-branch`
- commit to your local `new-branch`
- when you're ready for review, push `new-branch` to gerrit or whatever tool you're using
- reviewers make comments, you fix things in the same branch, until done
- when the review is approved, merge to `main` from within gerrit.
- now everybody might want to get your merged changes by fetching `main`

Comment: One small correction: `fetch origin main:main` is generally safe and will not lose any local commits. Only fast-forwards will be done, unless the refspec is prefixed with `+` or `-f` is specified.

Comment: Right, I will correct that. It never happens to me because guess what... I only commit to my own branches :)